# gui application at linux start up

Tags: linux, authentication

you r right for adding application at linux startup.

But my requirement is something different.

At this time i am able to execute my application at linux startup. But it starts at the time when linux authentication window appears.

But i want to start my application just after root user get authenticated by entering user name "root" and some "password".

I think, for this i will have to execute my application in the script for linux authentication script.
For this i want that linux script location in linux h.

Answer (score 1):

[Desktop Application Autostart Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html)

> By placing an application's .desktop file in one of the Autostart directories the application will be automatically launched during startup of the user's desktop environment after the user has logged in.